# Why is my unit test saying a page has not been rendered when it clearly has been?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, chai, sinon

This is the unit test in question:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const sinonChai = require('sinon-chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const appRefAPI = require('../../../../../../app/services/api');
const { getMarkAsManual, submitMarkAsManual } = require('../../../../../../app/services/handler/manual/mark-as-manual-handler');
const appRefResult = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(require('../../../response/application-received-full')));
const postData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(require('../../../response/post-app')));
const offerAccepted = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(require('../../../response/exception-offer-accepted')));

const { expect } = chai;
chai.use(sinonChai);

describe('details/mark-as-manual-handler.js', () => {
    let req;
    let res;
    let sandbox;

    describe.only('submitMarkAsManual()', async () => {
        before(() => {
            res = {
                render: () => ({})
            };
            req = {
                session: {}
            };
            sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
        });

        beforeEach(() => {
            sandbox.stub(res, 'render').returns({});
            sandbox.stub(appRefAPI, 'postClose').returns([200, postData]);
        });

        afterEach(() => {
            sandbox.restore();
        });

        it('should render-manually-process-confirmation', () => {
            req.session.application_reference = 'EZ123456';
            req.session.data = offerAccepted
            req.body = {
                'manually-processed-day': '3',
                'manually-processed-month': '3',
                'manually-processed-year': '1999'
            }
            res.locals = {};
            res.locals.application_reference = req.session.application_reference;
            submitMarkAsManual(req, res);
            console.log(res.render)
            expect(res.render).to.have.been.calledOnceWith('pages/manually-process-confirmation');
        });
    });
});
```

This is the code it's looking at:

```
const submitMarkAsManual = async (req, res) => {
    const errors = [];
    let dd = req.body['manually-processed-day'];
    let mm = req.body['manually-processed-month'];
    let yyyy = req.body['manually-processed-year'];
    if (dd.length === 1) dd = '0'+dd;
    if (mm.length === 1) mm = '0'+mm;
    const credit_date = `${dd}/${mm}/${yyyy}`
    res.locals = req.session.data;
    res.locals.credit_date = credit_date;
    if (util.isValidDate(credit_date) === false) {
        errors.push('date-invalid');
        res.render('pages/mark-as-manual', { errors });
    } else {
        let data = {
            "application_id": req.session.application_reference,
            "closure_reason": "offer_response_processed_manually",
            "credit_date": credit_date
        }
        const response = await callAPI.postClose(data);
        if (response[0] === 200 && response[1].status === 'SUCCESS') {
            console.log('success!!!!')
            res.render('pages/manually-process-confirmation');
        }else{
            res.redirect('/budgeting-loans-ui/problem-with-service');
        }
    }
};
```

And from this I get the following message:

```
1) details/mark-as-manual-handler.js
       submitMarkAsManual()
         should render-manually-process-confirmation:
     AssertionError: expected render to have been called exactly once with arguments pages/manually-process-confirmation
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/unit/app/services/handler/manual/mark-as-manual-handler-test.js:85:45)
      at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:463:21)
```

In the code being tested, just before the render, I've put in a console.log call that outputs 'success!!!!'. When I run the test, this pops out so I know it reaches (and presumably executes) the render.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `submitMarkAsManual()` is asynchronous, but you don't wait for it to complete before you run your assertion - at which point `res.render()` actually has not executed yet.

Answer (score 0):

Move the following lines to an asynchronous function:

```
 submitMarkAsManual(req, res);
 console.log(res.render)
 expect(res.render).to.have.been.calledOnceWith('pages/manually-process-confirmation');
```

with a call to an asynchronous function:

```
const sub = async (req, res) => {
    await submitMarkAsManual(req, res)
    expect(res.render).to.have.been.calledOnceWith('pages/manually-process-confirmation');
}
```

(Thanks to IAmDranged for pointing the way.)